# How to create change item from list A to list B using animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a list of words, and arrange them into 1 complete sentence similar to below image. I'm thinking of the idea of ​​creating 2 Widget lists and animating between widget list changes, but don't know how to do it yet. I would like to see if flutter has a lib to do that, or if not, what do I have to research to make such a feature,

[realistic image that i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiuIe.gif)

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://pub.dev/packages/local_hero

Comment: Draggable is your answer. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html

Comment: I got what I wanted by using LocalHero. Thank Andrija! Thank all.!